# Qunit : How i finish test async without know acceptCallCount?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, qunit

Here is an example for Qunit test async, i want to finish it (result of the test) into the function async like is this example setTimeout :

```
QUnit.test("test", function(assert) {
    var done = assert.async(10); // 10 is just example
    assert.ok(true, "succed");
    done();
    setTimeout(function () {
    // here callback async, i want to finish the test, 
    // but i don't know the vlaue of acceptCallCount (assert.async(acceptCallCount));

    }, 1000);
    assert.ok(true, "succed");
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*(this is more a comment however too new for SO to comment!)*

note that 'async' function comes with Qunit 2.
Check your Qunit version.

> Note that all the new APIs of QUnit 2.0 are already usable in QUnit 1.23.0

if you are before 1.23.0, you should upgrade or use the old method with Qunit.start().